# Can I use testflight for more than 90 days?

Tags: ios

testflight is available for 90 days. But if you want to use it for more than 90 days, if you just upload a new build file, will another 90 days be added based on that basis?

Comment: Each new version will start with 90 days. Old versions will continue to count down.

Comment: Then, if I keep uploading new build files, is it possible for unlimited beta testing?

Comment: yes. I read that some programmers use this way to distribute app (to small number of people) without going through the review process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and if you just increment the build number it won’t require fresh approval for external testers.